# Wordpress - can I get rewrite rules for a given path?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am writing a plugin, which routes URLs to a custom format.

Quite simply put I want to get rewrite rules for a given path, can I do this?

so for example, I need a function as follows:

```
$path = 'team/john-smith';

$rules =  get_rules($path)
```

$rules is now something like

```
index.php?team=john-smith&post_type=team&name=john-smith;
```

or alternatively, the actual rewrite rules array (and I can build the string myself...)

```
array("team" => "john-smith", "post_type" => "team", "name"=> "john-smith");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this function in includes/rewrite.php:

`function url_to_postid($url)`

My guess is that to get the actual rewrite rules, you would use:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$rewrite = $wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules();
```

Or call `page_rewrite_rules()`.  There's a few interesting looking bits of code in that file.